# Colour highlighting output based on regex in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'd like to know if I can colour highlight the output of a shell command that matches certain strings.

For example, if I run myCommand, with the output below:

```
> myCommand
DEBUG foo bar
INFO bla bla
ERROR yak yak
```

I'd like all lines matching ^ERROR\s.* to be highlighted red.

Similarly, I'd like the same highlighting to be applied to the output of grep, less etc...

EDIT: I probably should mention that ideally  I'd  like to enable this feature globally via a 'profile' option in my .bashrc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to enable this globally, you'll want a terminal feature, not a process that you pipe output into, because a pipe would be disruptive to some command (two problems are that stdout and stderr would appear out-of-order and buffered, and that some commands just behave differently when outputting to a terminal).

I don't know of any “conventional” terminal with this feature. It's easily done in Emacs, in a `term` buffer: configure `font-lock-keywords` for `term-mode`.

However, you should think carefully whether you really want that feature all the time. What if the command has its own colors (e.g. `grep --color`, `ls --color`)? Maybe it would be better to define a short alias to a [colorizer command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267400/colour-highlighting-output-based-on-regex-in-shell/4269167#4269167) and run `myCommand 2>&1|c` when you want to colorize `myCommand`'s output. You could also [alias some specific always-colorize commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267400/colour-highlighting-output-based-on-regex-in-shell/4269864#4269864).

Note that the return status of a pipeline is its *last* command, so if you run `myCommand | c`, you'll get the status of `c`, not `myCommand`. Here's a bash wrapper that avoids this problem, which you can use as `w myCommand`:

```
w () {
  "$@" | c
  return $PIPESTATUS[0]
}
```

Comment: Note that `w` is a utility in Linux similar to `who`.

Answer (score 64):

There is an answer in [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/199088/highlight-console-search-output-while-displaying-entire-command-output/199212#199212):

```
your-command | grep -E --color 'pattern|$'
```

or

```
your-command | grep --color 'pattern\|$'
```

This will *"match your pattern or the end-of-line on each line. Only the pattern is highlighted..."*

Comment: Check the `grep` man page, especially the documentation for the `GREP_COLORS` environment variable.

Comment: Here's a version of this as a function you can add to .bashrc/.bash_profile (replace --- with line breaks!): # Highlight all occurrences of a certain string in text piped to this function. ---# Example usage: echo 'hello world' | hilight world
---function highlight { grep -E --color "$1|\$"; }

Answer (score 29):

You can use programs such as:

- [spc (Supercat)](http://supercat.nosredna.net/index.html)
- [grc (Generic Colouriser)](http://korpus.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html)
- [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/)
- histring
- [pygmentize](http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/)
- grep --color

You can do something like this, but the commands won't see a tty (some will refuse to run or behave differently or do weird things):

```
exec > >(histring -fEi error)    # Bash
```

Answer (score 14):

You could try (maybe needs a bit more escaping):

```
BLUE="$(tput setaf 4)"
BLACK="$(tput sgr0)"
command | sed "s/^ERROR /${BLUE}ERROR ${BLACK}/g"
```

Comment: To highlight gcc errors and warnings from make, save the following as `~/bin/errmake`: `make $@ 2>&1 | sed -e "s/error:/$(tput setab 1 ; tput bold)error:$(tput sgr0)/g" -e "s/warning:/$(tput setab 4 ; tput bold)warning:$(tput sgr0)/g"`

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
tail -f yourfile.log | egrep --color 'DEBUG|'
```

where DEBUG is the text you want to highlight.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the hl command avalaible on github :
git clone http://github.com/mbornet-hl/hl

Then :
myCommand  | hl -r '^ERROR.*'

You can use the $HOME/.hl.cfg configuration file to simplify the command line.
hl is written in C (source is available).
You can use up to 42 differents colors of text.

Answer (score 2):

Use awk.

```
 COLORIZE_AWK_COMMAND='{ print $0 }'
 if [ -n "$COLORIZE" ]; then
     COLORIZE_AWK_COMMAND='
     /pattern1/ { printf "\033[1;30m" }
     /pattern2/ { printf "\033[1;31m" }
     // { print $0 "\033[0m"; }'
 fi
```

then later you can pipe your output

```
... | awk "$COLORIZE_AWK_COMMAND"
```

printf is used in the patterns so we don't print a newline, just set the color.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably enable it for specific commands using aliases and user defined shell functions wihtout too much trouble.  If your coloring errors I assume you want to process stderr. Since stderr in unbuffered you would probably want to line buffer it by sending through a fifo.