# How to parse commands and color it?

Tags: shell, command, text-coloring

I like the idea of command prompt coloring, and I was wondering how I can extend that to have the shell color the commands as I type it in or via tab completion. So for example, when I finish typing 'gcc', the shell should recognize that it is a valid command and color it green. If the command is not a recognized command then it should be colored in red and boldfaced.

This feature will help tremendously in typing in correct commands especially if you have long commandlines with pipelined commands which accidentally contain a typo. All command typos will be colored red and boldfaced so that I can easily identify which command I typed incorrectly.

Comment: If you want to add color to the gcc output, install `colorgcc` but if you want to do by yourself, check the colorgcc code (it's a perl script) and take a look on how it works

Comment: Probably this other question is helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267400/colour-highlighting-output-based-on-regex-in-shell

Comment: @h3nr1x - I am not looking to color the _output_ of gcc. I want the shell to recognize that I have typed a command at the prompt and as a feedback of the recognition I want it to be colored. Currently the shell will wait for me to press Enter and then if there is a typo in the command, it will inform me that the command is not found. I want the shell to recognize commands on the fly and tell me straight away that the command is incorrect.

Comment: @JuanFranciscoCanteroHurtado - The link you provided is for coloring the output of a command. I want the shell to dynamically parse each keystroke that I make at the prompt and at locations where it expects a command it must recognize that a valid command has been typed and color it green or red if its correct or incorrect respectively. I suppose the solution would be a background job that executes when I start the terminal and examine the words that I type in and match those words with a list of recognized commands and color it appropriately.

Comment: OK, sorry for the noise.

Comment: Maybe you could trap the key press as stated here [link1](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/59605-trap-key-press-script.html), and then modify the prompt color prior to echoing back the typed command using some the techniques described here [link2](http://www.askapache.com/linux/bash-power-prompt.html) and here [link3](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt)

Comment: @h3nr1x - Interesting links, but the solution is still elusive.

Comment: A solution was provided by Igor, below.

Comment: This question is essentially the same as https://superuser.com/q/304211/980046

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can do this in `bash`. But it is possible in other shells, e.g. in `zsh` (see: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting ) or in `fish` (see: http://fishshell.com/ ).

Comment: My bad...I meant `bash`. But as Igor mentioned, it may not be possible in `bash` anyway.