# Is it possible to colorize the output of gnu parallel with grep?

Tags: bash, scripting, parallel-processing

I have a script that runs git commands over a number of repositories in parallel which gnu parallel. I would like to pass the output of the git command through grep and color certain parts, for example on git status I want the word "clean" to appear green. Is there any way to do this with gnu parallel and grep?

This is my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

START_DIR=`pwd`
export GIT_ARGS=$*
function do_git() {
    PROJECT_DIR=`dirname $1`
        cd $PROJECT_DIR
    echo ""
        pwd
        git $GIT_ARGS
        echo ""
        cd $START_DIR
}

export -f do_git

find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name ".git" | sort | parallel --max-procs 4 "do_git {}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to the end of your pipeline:

```
| grep -E --color 'clean|word1|word2|$'
```

Substitute and add or remove words as needed. The `$` causes all lines to match and pass through. The `--color` option is for GNU `grep`. Other versions of `grep` may use a different option.

Alternatively, there are [several utilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269167/26428) that can do colorization.

General tips:

- Avoid using all-caps variable names to prevent name collision with shell variables
- Use `$()` instead of backticks - they're more readable and more versatile (e.g. nesting)
- Using the `function` keyword is unnecessary
- See [BashFAQ/028](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) regarding trying to use the location of your script
- I don't think `GIT_ARGS` need to be exported

Comment: Excellent, I tried the exact same strategy but within my do_git function on the output of the git command. Chaining a few more piplines after the call to parallel works perfectly. Had to add --color=always to grep to preserve colors when piping grep output back into grep.

Answer (score 2):

To force grep to show colours when using parallel, try `grep --color=always`

Comment: It's interesting - I have `grep` command inside a function for gnu parallel and only option which works is `--color=always`. Other `--color` options don't colorize matches.

Answer (score 0):

I'll see if I could give a good suggestion about showing the color.

Meanwhile I think you could improve your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function do_git {
    PROJECT_DIR=${1%.git}
    cd "$PROJECT_DIR"
    echo
    pwd
    git "${@:2}"
    echo
}

export -f do_git

find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '.git' | sort | parallel --max-procs 4 do_git '{}' "$@"
```

You don't have to change back with cd "$START_DIR" since it's run in a subshell (in parallel perhaps) and won't affect the calling shell.