# Grep highlight a pattern other than the searched one

Tags: bash, grep

I am using grep to search some log files, my log entries looks like:

```
[2013-10-16 14:39:17] {"email":"email@host.com", "tel":"123456789", "address":"some address", "status":"0"}
```

(this is a sample, each entry has a lot of data)

What I want to do is: Filter with a pattern and highlight another pattern, for example I filter for status=1

```
cat log | grep 'status":1'
```

This works perfectly, and outputs something like:

[2013-10-16 14:39:17] {"email":"email@host.com", "tel":"123456789", "address":"some address", "**status":"1**"}

what I want to do is to highlight the email in the output to have something like:

[2013-10-16 14:39:17] {**"email":"email@host.com"**, "tel":"123456789", "address":"some address", "**status":"1**"}

Note, I just want to highlight the email, not filter!

is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear _why_ would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `grep` again for the pattern you want to highlight:

`cat log | grep 'status":"1' | grep '"email":"[^"]*"'`

Answer (score 2):

For the sole purpose of highlighting, you might take a look at https://github.com/nicoulaj/rainbow

Here are some other highlighters listed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269167/363281

Comment: I don't have rights to install anything, just checking some logs for debugging purpose...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have highlighting already working you would do:

```
$ grep -e '"email":"[^"]*"' -e '"status":"1"'  file
```

If you don't have highlighting already set use the `--color` option:

```
$ grep --color=auto -e '"email":"[^"]*"' -e '"status":"1"'  file
```

This would filter by status' of `1` and highlight all emails and status'. If you only want the email highlighting then:

```
$ grep '"status":"0"' file | grep '"email":"[^"]*"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, try to manipulate the text filtered using using `awk`. With file like this

```
$ cat test.txt
[2013-10-16 14:39:17] {"email":"email1@host.com", "status":"1"}
[2013-10-16 14:39:17] {"email":"email2@host.com", "status":"0"}
[2013-10-16 14:39:17] {"email":"email3@host.com", "status":"1"}
[2013-10-16 14:39:17] {"email":"email4@host.com", "status":"0"}
[2013-10-16 14:39:17] {"email":"email5@host.com", "status":"1"}
[2013-10-16 14:39:17] {"email":"email6@host.com", "status":"0"}
[2013-10-16 14:39:17] {"email":"email7@host.com", "status":"1"}
```

Try this command

```
cat test.txt | grep \"status\":\"1\" | awk '{print "\033[32m",$3,"\033[0m",$4}'
```